# compare text (with dashes) using regex shell script

Tags: regex, grep

I want to check if my  variable has this format `--- foobar---> <some other stuff>`
In other words, I want to know if the text starts with `--- foobar --->`

So I used `grep -q` but got this error:

```
$echo "---  foobar---> subtree " | grep -q "--- fooobar--->*" 
grep: unrecognized option `--- fooobar--->*'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

(This is `OSX`, and `grep's version is:`

```
$ grep --v
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

)

How do I re-write my regex to match the expected string?

Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify on what you are expecting the * to act upon?
right now as it is written you are telling it to match your string with 0 or more '>' at the end.  If you mean any character after your expression it would look like this."--- fooobar--->.*"

Comment: As a secondary comment, you can build and test regular expressions at [www.regexlib.com](www.regexlib.com)

Comment: Just added the clarification. I want to check if the text starts with `--- foobar --->`

Comment: if you want to check if it starts with it then might I suggest it read "^--- foobar --->"  This will check if your text starts with foobar.  I am looking up to see of '>' is a special character, and it may need to be escaped using a '\' and then would look like this "^--- foobar ---\>"

Comment: I confirmed using the regexlib.com regular expression tester that > does not need to be escapped.  I would next suggest using as the answer is below from F.J about the -e option.  That should fix it.  But remember to add a '^' to the beginning of your expression if you are seeing if a line starts with your pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the error by adding `-e` just before your regex:

```
grep -q -e "--- fooobar--->*"
```

From man page:

```
 -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
        Use PATTERN as the pattern; useful to protect patterns beginning with -.
```

As for the regex itself, `*` in regex means "repeat the previous character zero or more times", so your regex is checking for `--- fooobar---` and then zero or more `>` characters.

If you want to match any number of any character, use `.*` instead:

```
grep -q -e "--- fooobar--->.*"
```

However since it looks like you are just checking whether or not the line matches, the `.*` at the end isn't really changing anything, it would behave the same way if you removed it entirely.

You may also want to add a `^` to the start of your pattern, this is a beginning of line anchor so that you won't match lines like "some other content... --- fooobar---> baz".

Comment: You may want to update your answer for one last case.  He is looking for "begins with" for the pattern.  so adding a '^' to the start of the pattern.  I realize that this is just a small point in the overall answer, just looking to ensure completeness of the answer.  But I agree. +1 to your solution.